# Can I bind a tixBalloon Widget to a Text widget tag?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, balloon, tix

I am wanting to mimic the behavior of the 'abbr' tag of HTML in a tkinter Text widget. The Tix Balloon widget looks like it would be a perfect fit, but I can't figure out how to bind it to a text tag instead of a whole widget. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible.  It is possible to place a label inside a text widget and bind the balloon to the label.

Comment: is there perhaps a function that the balloon widget uses to make itself visible that I could bind to the tag?

Answer (score 1):

you might be better off writing your own balloon widget in plain Tkinter

see http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ToolTip for an example

re: binding to a tag in a text widget: Pmw balloon can do it